# Fetching all znodes with data from Apache Zookeeper using Java

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to get all the znodes from Apache Zookeeper using **CuratorFramework**. I have written a **BFS** java program to visit the znodes and got all the data, but it is really slow. Is there a better way to fetch all the znodes and its data from zookeeper using Java. Thanks in advance.